# what is the meaning or use of 暗転

Tags: words, usage

I am reading an article about a pro figure skater who is recovering from an injury. The author talks about the skater beginning to heal, but then re-injuring herself.

順調に快方に向かうかと思えたが、暗転したのは＜日付＞。

I thought that 暗転 would mean something like "took a turn for the worse" but my dictionary said that it means "theatrical blackout" (not able to perform?) Is that correct? Can you also use it as "took a turn for the worse"

Thanks

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/8770/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to the Weblio entry for [暗転](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9A%97%E8%BB%A2), the first definition says, “A dark change,” and the second definition says, “A change for the worse”.

So I would say yes, you can.